# How to create a Json array in C# MVC Controller

Tags: c#, json

I have an List of Doors that looks like :

```
DoorId   DoorName  ControllerId ControllerName
------   --------  ------------ --------------

Door1    DoorOne   C1           C1
Door2    DoorTwo   C1           C1
Door3    DoorThree C2           C2
```

I need to format it like this :

```
            var doorsForSite = new[]
                {
                new { ControllerId ="C1",ControllerName="C1",IsChecked = "false",
                        Doors = new[]
                        {
                            new { DoorId="Door1",DoorName="DoorOne",Schedules = scheduleList},
                            new { DoorId="Door2",DoorName="DoorTwo",Schedules = scheduleList},
                        }

                    },
                new { ControllerId ="C2",ControllerName="C2",IsChecked = "false",
                        Doors = new[]
                        {
                            new { DoorId=  "Door3",DoorName="DoorThree",Schedules = scheduleList}
                        }

                    }
            };
```

That is group by `ControllerId` and `ControllerName` and then build the `Doors` array .

How to do it ?

Comment: Are you trying to serialize that array into json or to convert the list into that array?

Comment: Serialize the array into Json

Answer (score 0):

Install JSON.net [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) package. Use JsonConvert.SerializeObject [function](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm)

```
string jsonArray = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doorsForSite);
```